# Angular custom directive with isolate scope not firing ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Angular custom directive code:

*Template (ReviewStandards.html)*

```
<div class="review-standard" ng-repeat="standard in standards">
    <button ng-click="mark(standard)">Mark Complete</button>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
app.directive("reviewStandards", function ($parse, $state) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    templateUrl: function (elements, attrs) {
        return "/Scripts/App/Directives/Templates/ReviewStandards.html";
    },
    transclude: false,
    scope: {
        standards: "="
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        scope.mark = function (standard) {
            alert();
        };
    }
  };
});
```

The directive is used as:

```
<div review-standards standards="review.ReviewStandards"></div>
```

Where `standards` is just a JSON array of `standard` objects.

Problem is that the the `ng-click` is not firing the function when the button is clicked.  The scope is isolated - is this something to do with this or the fact that the button is in an `ng-repeat`?

Comment: How are you using directive inside ngRepeat?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question

Comment: How is `<div review-standards standards="review.ReviewStandards"></div>` related to the rest of the question?

Comment: That's just how the directive is being used in a parent page

Comment: Oh, I see. Use controllerAs notation or $parent.mark.

Comment: try ng-click in controller
controller: function($scope, $element){
         $scope.click = function(){
         }

Comment: that worked for me, are you sure don't have any error in your console?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/rz5LgehA8clcP930qHOx?p=preview

Comment: dude, please remove replace: true,from your directive, you didn't need to replace that

Comment: @charlietfl, Hm, i not see alert when click button in chrome in your punker

Comment: @Maher - Removing replace: true did the trick.  Can you post as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Try This, "i just remove the Replace from your codes"

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
      name: "a"
    },
    {
      name: "b"
    }
  ];


});

app.directive("reviewStandards", function() {
  var template = "<div class=\"review-standard\">" +
     "<div ng-repeat=\"standard in standards\">" +
      "{{standard.name}} " +
      "<button ng-click=\"mark(standard)\">Mark Complete</button>" +
     "<div><hr>" +
    "</div>";
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    transclude: false,
    template: template,
    scope: {
      standards: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      scope.mark = function(standard) {
        console.log(standard)
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div review-standards standards="data"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll try a bit explain **why** this happens.

Problems here with scope inheritance when using *replace:true* and in template just one element with *ng-repeat*.

If *replace:false*, template paste **inside** element with directive, so you get something like this

```
<div review-standards standards="review.ReviewStandards"> <!-- here isolated scope from review-standards directive -->
    <div class="review-standard" ng-repeat="standard in standards"> <!-- here child scope created with ng-repeat -->
        <button ng-click="mark(standard)">Mark Complete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, child scopes that created by *ng-repeat* inherits from *isolated* scope *review-standards* directive, and all property from isolated scope available in children scopes.

When used *replace:true*, template **replace** element with directive, si you get something like this

```
<div class="review-standard" ng-repeat="standard in standards" review-standards standards="review.ReviewStandards"> <!-- here child scope created with ng-repeat -->
    <button ng-click="mark(standard)">Mark Complete</button>
</div>
```

And most interesting in this case, that now children scopes *inherited* from *ng-controller*, but `$parent` property setup to *isolated* scope *review-standards* directive. So in children scope available all properties from *ng-controller* scope but **not** available from *isolated* scope *review-standards* directive.

Simplest way for solution, as suggest in nearby answer, just remove *replace:true*

Yet another way: a bit change template, like this

```
<div>
    <div class="review-standard" ng-repeat="standard in standards">
        <button ng-click="mark(standard)">Mark Complete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or a bit ugly solution: use **$parent** property instead hoping on inheritance

```
<div class="review-standard" ng-repeat="standard in $parent.standards">
    <button ng-click="$parent.mark(standard)">Mark Complete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - is a comprehensive explanation of something that's not immediately apparent